# PHP's OR binary logic

Tags: php, ruby, logic

Can someone please explain me why

```
echo "0123" | "3456";
```

Returns 3577 and why in ruby

```
0123 | 3456
```

Will return 3539

EDIT: This was a bad example since ruby's version is not strings.

But in JS

```
"0123" | "3456"
```

Will return 3539

EDIT: ELI5 :)

Comment: php -r "var_dump("0123" | "3456");"
`int(3539)`

Comment: var_dump("0123" | "3456"); returns 3577 for me.

Comment: You realise that strings are not numbers, so you're not comparing like with like between PHP and Ruby?

Comment: That's true. Ruby doesn't allow string | string comparisons.

Comment: So try doing `echo 0123 | 3456;` in PHP and see if it's different to Ruby then

Comment: It will be the same, but that's not the problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the PHP fragment is operating on strings, while the ruby fragment is operating on numbers. Also notice that in ruby the number 0123 is octal because of the initial 0.

In PHP the bitwise or between strings is computed as the bitwise or between each character, so the result will have first 0|3, which is 3, then 1|4, which is 5, then 2|5, which is 7, and then 3|6, which is 7. Note that the operation is computed with characters so for example 2|9 would give you `;`.

To see how the result is computed by ruby you have to first convert the second operand to base 8 or binary: it's 6600 in base 8, and the result of the bitwise or is therefore 6723 in base 8, or 3539 in decimal.

Comment: Why does JS return 3539 for: "0123" | "3456"?

Comment: @unska, again Javascript is converting the first number to octal not decimal.

Comment: You gave an awesome example how PHP does the calculation, could you give one for JS too?

Comment: JavaScript converts the strings to integers first, so "0123"|"3456" is computed as 123|3456 = 3579.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is simple: string and integer are not the same:

```
var_dump("0123" | "3456");//string(4) "3577"
var_dump(0123 | 3456); //int(3539)
```

also be aware about 0** notation for *oct* [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is sometimes weird:

```
echo 0123 | 3456; //0123 is interpret as an octal number
```

Return 3539

```
echo 123 | 3456;
```

Return 3579

```
echo (int)"0123" | (int)"3456";
```

Return 3579

```
echo "0123" | "3456";
```

Return 3577

If both the left-hand and right-hand parameters are strings, the bitwise operator will operate on the characters' ASCII values !!

Comment: Could you give me an example how the ascii operations will be calculated under the hood for those numbers?